# Whats wrong with this script?

Tags: python, rfid

I'm making an RFID scanner that will turn lights on if a card is present on the scanner, and off if no card is present.

Here's simplified code that represents the issue:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import MFRC522
import signal
import os

MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522()

def on():
print 'Lights on'
os.system("php /home/pi/www/RLY4.php")

def off():
    print 'Lights off'
    os.system("php /home/pi/www/RLY4-.php")

while True:
    (status,TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)
    if(status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK):
        on()
    else:
        off()
```

`status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK` is True whenever a card is present so the `on()` function should be called.

Whenever the card isn't present the lights turn off as they should, however whenever the card *is* present the lights alternate between on and off, both the if and else statements are being called.

What's going on with this script and why are both if and the else statements being called?

Comment: Please always try to be more specific in title. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you using this module? https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python/blob/master/MFRC522.py

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. There's an infinite loop, is it just possible the `on` gets called one loop then `off` gets called the very next one? Both conditions cannot be met the same time.

Comment: Tankor, actually the problem is (I suppose) that this line: "(status,TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)" is setting status once to MI_OK, once to MI_ERR, which leads to different outcome of if statement every loop iteration.

Comment: Does that mean your question is " why is  `status` and `TagType` different between loops, without changing anything outside the script"?

Comment: I think so, but let's wait for OP to confirm :)

Answer (score 0):

it's ok I figured it out im using two while loops now and alternating between each every time I scan the card:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import MFRC522
import signal
import datetime
import os
import time
import math
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style
colorama.init()

scan1 = True
scan2 = False
continue_reading = True

MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522()
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
print 'press CTRL+C to stop'

def on():
    print 'Lights on'
    os.system("php /home/pi/www/RLY4.php")

def off():
    print 'Lights off'
    os.system("php /home/pi/www/RLY4-.php")

def sayHi():
    print 'hi'

while True:
    while scan1:
        (status,TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)
        if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
            print 'card detected at first scan, switching systems on.'
        (status,uid) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Anticoll()
        if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
            UID = repr(str(uid[0])+","+str(uid[1])+","+str(uid[2])+","+str(uid[3]))
            UID0 = str(UID)
            print UID0
            on()
            scan1 = False
            scan2 = True

    while scan2:
        (status,TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)
        if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
            print 'card detected at second scan, switching systems off.'
        (status,uid) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Anticoll()
        if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
            UID = repr(str(uid[0])+","+str(uid[1])+","+str(uid[2])+","+str(uid[3]))
            UID0 = str(UID)
            print UID0
            off()
            scan1 = True
            scan2 = False
        sayHi()
```

this may be an inefficient way though so if anyone knows a better way then feel free to correct me...